# Adding custom attribute to a system class

Tags: reflection, types, attributes, reflection.emit

I want to add classes from `System.Activites.Presentation` my custom attribute. I tried to do it with `emit(TypeBuilder, ModuleBuilder, AssemblyBuilder)`. Is it possible to change an existing type by adding an attribute to it? Or how to tell `TypeBuilder`, so that it uses an existing data type? Or inherit from a given type?
Thank you.

Comment: which classes are you talking about? Are they marked as 'sealed'? If not, you can create your own custom class deriving from original and adding custom attributes

Comment: Class from namespace Windows.System.Activities. I want add my custom attribute DisplayName (string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add attributes to `System` classes but, if they are not marked as `Sealed` you can create your custom class deriving from original and adding custom attribute.

All your code must call derived class, that is identical to the original except on the attribute added.

```
[MyAttribute(DisplayName="Name shown")]
public class MyActivity: System.Activities.Activity
{
}
/// <summary>
/// Custom attribute definition
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public sealed class MyAttribute : System.Attribute
{


    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the attribute
    /// </summary>
         public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Allow access to the attribute
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="prop"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
      public static string GetDisplayName(System.Reflection.MemberInfo prop)
    {
        string field = null;
        object[] attr = prop.GetCustomAttributes(false);
        foreach (object a in attr)
        {
            MyAttribute additional = a as MyAttribute;
            if (additional != null)
            {
                field = additional.DisplayName;
            }
        }
        return field;
    }


}
```